# Oracle database issues

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I had my database working properly but I had an issue and when I tried to repair it I executed the following command

`alter tablespace system add datafile '/var/oracle/oradata/data.dbf' size 10000m autoextend on maxsize unlimited;`

Then I noticed that the command didn't resolve my problem then I deleted the file `data.dbf...` But the problem that I'm having right now is that when I'm trying to restart my database it doesn't run.

I looked and didn't find how to fix the problem. Can someone help me? Any help please... I'm down

Comment: Did you try `drop datafile`?

Comment: what was your initial issue?

Comment: @mustaccio i dont have even the possibility to connect in my db i'm getting this error `ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress`

Comment: @JoeW my initial issue was that when i was execute a `select` query it's was giving an error to extend my tablespace

Comment: Posting the exact error message would help as it seems strange that you would need to extend the system tablespace to run a query. Also providing your version of oracle will help.

Comment: The error message was this @JoeW `01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
           a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
           files to the tablespace indicated.` The query that i was execute was a `Select` but the target table has 7 478 2254 datas. I'm using oracle 11g

Comment: You might want to check out this https://blog.rackspace.com/can-database-runs-temp-space

Comment: Thanks for this docs @JoeW but my current issue you didn't say something. What do you advice me to do?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have enough expertise in that area, It just seemed strange what tablespace you where extending.

Comment: Just for clarification, did you add a datafile for the SYSTEM tablespace and then delete it? How did you delete it? Also, the error message you posted was related to a temporary segment, which would reside in a temporary tablespace, so adding a datafile to the SYSTEM tablespace would not correct that problem.

Comment: Yes @JoeW i added a datafile for the SYSTEM and then i deleted it that physically

Comment: @JohnA - the fact that the error msg mentions 'temporary segment' does NOT mean that the TS in question is the TEMP TS.  Any time a new extent is allocated, it is "temporary".  All extents, in all TS, are "temporary" during the initial allocation (including any necessary file extension)  and only made "not temporary" when the allocation is successfully completed. Kind of like a transaction in the redo not being "completet" until COMMITed.

Comment: @EdStevens TEMP was suggested because the error resulted from a SELECT statement.

Comment: @EdStevens Also, ORA-01652 typically points to a TEMPORARY tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted the **SYSTEM** tablespace datafile as you say, and do not have a backup, there is no recovery. You will need to recreate the database.

Side note, you should never delete a datafile directly at the OS level and never the SYSTEM.

Comment: then I lost all my datas???
Just for clarification @Ross the datafile that i deleted was a new one which had nothing but i have others datafile that were working before properly. There is only no way to create a new database by using those datafile which were working before?

Comment: Ok, that's good then. What state is the database in? Running? Was it already shutdown? If you have some screenshots of where your system01.dbf file is, as well as some sqlplus screenshots of the state of the database, that will be helpful.

Comment: The state of the database is in shutdown state

Comment: ```connect / as sysdba;```

```startup mount;```

```ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '/var/oracle/oradata/data.dbf' OFFLINE DROP;```

```alter database open;```

As long as you still have your original system01.dbf file!

Comment: It's gives me this error `ORA-01589: must use RESETLOGS or NORESETLOGS option for database open`

Comment: ```alter database open resetlogs;```

Comment: I'm not undesrtanding any thing im down... oh God

Comment: `
ORA-01245: offline file 1 will be lost if RESETLOGS is done
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/var/oracle/oradata/INTRANET/system01.dbf'`

Comment: You are not providing me the proper information. You stated you had a separate datafile you named 'data.dbf'.

Comment: All my tablespaces are there 
`/var/oracle/oradata/INTRANET/users01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/INTRANET/undotbs01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/INTRANET/sysaux01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/INTRANET/system01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/INTRANETdata.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/INTRANET/data.dbf`